# Setting Time with interval of 1 minute

Tags: python, time, time-series

I have a dataset which comprises of minutely data for 2 stocks over 3 months. I have to create  date in the first column and time (with interval of 1 minute) in the next column for 3 months. I am attaching the snap of 1 such data set. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

[Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKqLF.png)

Comment: Could you provide some data in text for as a code, pictures are a bit difficult to handle. Do you have the date and tie of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Create 3 month range numpy array of dates and time with minute frequency

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', end='3/31/2021', freq='min')
```

-Isolate dates

```
date = date_rng.date
```

-Isolate times

```
time = date_rng.time
```

-Create pandas dataframe with 2 columns (date and time)

```
pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'time': time})
```

-Then simply concat the new dataframe with your existing dataframe on the column axis.

***** Remove Saturday and Sunday *****

You could remove weekends by creating a column with weekend day names and then taking a slice of the dataframe exluding Saturday and Sunday:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2021', end='3/31/2021', freq='min')
date = date_rng.date
time = date_rng.time
day = date_rng.day_name()
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'time': time, 'day': day})
```

Remove Sat and Sun with this code:

```
sat = df.day != 'Saturday'
sun = df.day != 'Sunday'
df = df[sat & sun]
```

As for Holidays, you could use the same method but you would need a list of the holidays applicable in your region.

****** Trading times ******

```
marketOpen = datetime.strptime('9:15:00', "%H:%M:%S").time()
marketClose = datetime.strptime('15:59:00', "%H:%M:%S").time()

df = df[(df.time >= marketOpen) & (df.time <= marketClose)]
```

******* Exclude specific day ******

```
holiday = datetime.strptime("03/30/2021", "%m/%d/%Y").date()
df = df[df.date != holiday]
```

> **Lastly, don't forget to reset your dataframe's index.**

Comment: Hello, Thank you for sharing the code. partially the issue is resolved. But now I am stuck with another issue. How to exclude Saturday, Sundays and other holidays from the date time?

Comment: See the edited answer above.

Comment: Merry Christmas  and thanks a loot!

Comment: I need another filter. Time should be between 9.15am to 15.59(typical trading hours in USA). how to go about it

Comment: See edit for open and close times

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another request -the last one. I got the holiday list for NYSE from 2019 to 2021 but not sure how to exclude these dates. Seeking your help for the same. From below URL you can have the holiday list                                                          https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20181204005629/en/NYSE-Group-Announces-2019-2020-and-2021-Holiday-and-Early-Closings-Calendar

Comment: Using datetime.strptime (as I showed you above), you can format a datetime object for each one of these holidays (there aren't too many). Then you could remove these dates from the original dataframe in the same way I showed you how to do it for the open and close times (i.e. creating a new dataframe from a slice of the original dataframe after excluding the holidays). You got this!

Comment: Got it somewhat... I am writing below codes.. code is working fine.. but dates are note getting excluded     Holidays= df.date != "1/21/2019"
Holidays1 =df.date != "2/18/2019"
df = df[sat & sun & Holidays & Holidays1]

Comment: See edit for method to exclude specific days. You'll have to play around with the date format to make it match the format you will be using.

Comment: Is your question answered? Please mark it as such if it is.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much Joey!